# Hasura crashed while going through the tutorial

Tags: graphql, hasura, hasura-jwt

I was going through the Hasura tutorial at the following site, and for some reason "Hasura Console" crashed.

https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-collaborative-todo-app-with-realtime-graphql-using-hasura

The timing of the crash is not clear, but I think it was when I opened the react sample app, authenticated, and added a task.

### Current status

#### Hasura console

(Free plan)

It's crashing.
The following statement was displayed in the hasura console.

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

#### Heroku PostgresDB

It's working fine.

When I checked on the "heroku postgres overview", health was shown as available.

#### Heroku logs

Logs were retrieved from the Heroku server using the CLI.

```sh
2021-07-07T00:03:47.000822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/v1/graphql" host=toto-inu3.herokuapp.com request_id=87086b11-27e0-44ef-a4da-04ca203af092 fwd="my ip..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-07-07T00:03:58.533683+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/v1/graphql" host=toto-inu3.herokuapp.com request_id=ef9a1f3e-dffc-4a1b-8266-e18b7ddfc06b fwd="my ip..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-07-07T00:04:09.872896+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/v1/graphql" host=toto-inu3.herokuapp.com request_id=2fd61c74-e0ba-4ece-b5b2-67faaa848c8f fwd="my ip..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-07-07T00:04:22.097603+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/v1/graphql" host=toto-inu3.herokuapp.com request_id=a20b4af1-925c-46cb-937b-1c3d71ade87c fwd="my ip..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-07-07T00:04:26.300647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=OPTIONS path="/v1/graphql" host=toto-inu3.herokuapp.com request_id=a6f33560-23c6-45ce-99b8-aea0e4225dc8 fwd="my ip..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-07-07T00:04:33.557640+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/v1/graphql" host=toto-inu3.herokuapp.com request_id=33ef0621-d489-488d-94ae-158d25fb5d96 fwd="my ip..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-07-07T00:04:44.698673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/v1/graphql" host=toto-inu3.herokuapp.com request_id=58a1de21-c975-4c5e-99f9-ac27b8d3aaac fwd="my ip..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-07-07T00:04:56.013882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/v1/graphql" host=toto-inu3.herokuapp.com request_id=16ccadb3-a548-40bd-82a2-72d4147413d8 fwd="my ip..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

### My idea

Since I created the application on Hasura's Free plan, I think there is a possibility that it crashed because it exceeded the "60 requests/minute" limit.

Even if this is the case, I can't find a way to revert the crash...

Please help!

## It was resolved!!!

Thank you all for your comments!

I have checked the Heroku logs and the issue has been resolved successfully.

It seems that when deploying Hasura on Heroku, the
Heroku > Settings > Config Vars
If I enclose the value of "HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET" in single quotation marks, Hasura seems to crash.

---

This may not be necessary already, but I'll answer the comments for those who refer to this page in the future.

> Is Hasura deployed on Heroku (as mentioned in the blog post) or have you deployed it on Hasura Cloud? The crash logs you have shared seems to be from Heroku

I deployed Hasura on Heroku, not Hasura Cloud.

I'll Share a SS of the configuration part of...

[Heroku > Settings > Config Vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRFvT.png)

Comment: Is Hasura deployed on Heroku (as mentioned in the blog post) or have you deployed it on Hasura Cloud? The crash logs you have shared seems to be from Heroku.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! About your question: I suppose it's more appropriate for bug report for either hasura team or heroku

Comment: It would be better if you made edits to original post instead of writing in answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Alex!
I've corrected it to add to the original post.